# Change of measure when calibrating real-world dynamics

Tags: calibration, real-world-measure

If I want to simulate a process (say, a set of forward rates) under a real-world measure, can I use option prices / implied vols to calibrate some of the parameters and do I need to change the measure from the real-world to a risk-neutral one in order to do this? Any references on this subject would be welcome.